# Rename lots of files from yyyy-dd-mm_hh-ss.7z --> yyyy-mm-dd_hh-ss.7z

Tags: windows-7, file-rename, batch-rename

As it turns out, in a script I wrote a while ago to do SVN backup, I messed up the date format. Now I have about 60 files, all named badly.

How can I quickly rename these files, so that `mm` and `dd` are switched round?

[image: a]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Windows 7, this can be easily done using [ReNamer](http://www.filecluster.com/downloads/ReNamer.html).

Just add files to be renamed and create a RegEx rule (with 'skip extension' disabled) so as to replace `(\d{4})(-\d\d)(-\d\d)(_\d\d-\d\d.7z)` with `$1$3$2$4`.

**Screenshots:**

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: Thanks for this Roney! I already have *Bulk Rename Here* installed, so I used that instead. The RegEx just needed changing to `^(\d{4})(-\d\d)(-\d\d)(_\d\d-\d\d.7z)` (added `^`), the replacement box needed to be `\1\3\2\4`, and the *Include Ext* box needed to be checked. Thanks again!